# Sending Touch Screen Display data connected to arduino to Computer

Tags: python, c, arduino, touchscreen

I would like to register or display the data generated when the touch screen,connected to Arduino, is pressed or used to the computer?

How do I send data from the display to the computer via Arduino. I making  a car dashboard for a racing simulator which will work with unreal engine 5. I need to know how to interface the touchscreen display with my PC via Arduino.

Comment: what have you written so far? We don't do code writing. If you have a question or facing difficulty, show your code and explain the problem, we will see what we can help you to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what type of touch screen you have, there will likely be a library that you can install either by the library manager, or downloading a .zip file that has the correct structure to be added in to the Arduino libraries.

You will see that both of those options are available from the menu in the Arduino IDE or editor.

So check the display to find out which chip it uses, then search for a library which drives that chip. Install using one of the methods above.

Once installed, there will be a new set of example programs for that library and you will have coding examples that will answer your question more fully.